# Beats audio driver for hp dv6-7040tx

Tags: drivers, sound, hp, alsa

Here is the model of my laptop: http://www.gadgetsguru.com/hp-dv6-7040tx-lowest-price-spec-cheap-sale-india-15613.aspx

As the specs say, it has quad speakers with a sub-woofer... When i was using windows 8, i had no problems. But, now only two speakers work and no sub-woofer.

I recently switched over to ubuntu and i'm a newbie :).. Please post a step-by-step guide for installing audio driver.

I heard that alsa is pre installed in ubuntu 13.04

Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: You do not need installation but configuration. Please show the output of the [alsa-info script](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo).

Comment: This is what i got: 
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6ef7873adba40f9301449c0ab1bd42ee2af3dfbb

Comment: Does `speaker-test -D hw:0,0 -t wav -c 6` work?

Comment: `speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is hw:0,0
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 6 channels
WAV file(s)
Channels count (6) not available for playbacks: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument`




This is the output i got!

Comment: Does it work with `-c 4` instead?

Comment: I could not get it working - first I tried to enter sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and add line options snd-hda-intel model=ref as described in other solution - it did not work at first. But after changing 'ref' value to the default hostname of my laptop which is always set up by the system during the installation process, it worked perfect. I think that by typing ref, it pulls the hostname and tries to compare the settings somehow, but if You set other name than default, which is a laptop model, it will not work unless You enter the command like that: options snd-hda-intel model=HP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO problem @CL. Got it working... Did the following:

First, edit the following file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Uncommment and change the values of these lines:

```
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
default-sample-channels = 4
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,center,lfe
```

Second, edit the following file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Add the following line to the end:

```
load-module module-combine channels=4 channel_map=front-left,front-right,center,lfe
```