# how to enable beats audio for hp 7040tx for the intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have installed 12.04.3 in my HP DV6 7040tx. It has quad speakers + one sub woofer (Beats Audio). I went through many posts and i was not able to find the solution. I tried the package

```
    hda-jack-retask
```

But, i can hear only much of bass like voice and music.

Here are the configuration when i run `lspci | grep "Audio"`

```
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

when i run `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* |grep Codec`

```
    Codec: IDT 92HD91BXX
    Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
```

when i run `aplay -l`

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

when i run `lspci -v | grep -A 8 -i audio`

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1818
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
Memory at d4610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
```

Can i get a solution to make use of my beats audio in Ubuntu. Thank you for trying to help me

Comment: Similar or the same? http://askubuntu.com/questions/302340/is-there-a-way-to-enable-beats-audio-from-within-linux

Comment: Similar. I already went through that post. But, as i mentioned earlier, my sound has extra BASS which i can't control. The voice is not clear at all

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/299769/beats-audio-driver-for-hp-dv6-7040tx  -- you should edit your question with all the posts and techniques you have tried.

Comment: I created a post in spanish with the same problem ( i have a HP Envy M4).
With this instructions i installed the HDA Jack Retask (http://www.benbristow.co.uk/2013/08/fix-low-sound-with-intel-hda-on-ubuntu/) And there are instructions to put on the subwoofer (http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/) But, with this, my headphones doesnt work :( Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP Envy dv7 with beats audio, probably similar sound hardware.

In Ubuntu **12.04** I got it working by doing `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and adding the line `options snd-hda-intel model=ref` at the bottom, then save the file and reboot.

Now under Ubuntu **14.04** this solution doesn't work anymore for me, but I found a solution on [this thread in the Gentoo forums](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-859769.html):

- do `gksudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa`
- add the line `load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe` at the bottom
- save the file, close all windows and reboot
- open sound settings (through system settings or by clicking on the volume icon in unity and choosing "sound settings") and you'll have an extra configuration "*simultaneaous sound output*". Click on this, then test the sound using the "*test sound*" button to the right. For me 5 speakers out of 6 work now, only the subwoofer doesn't. Not perfect, but close.

Hope this helps...