# Sound driver problem

Tags: drivers, sound, hardware, 17.10, soundcard

I have a HP desktop with IDT 92HD89E Beats Audio sound chip, and there is no driver for it. At the time I had Ubuntu 14.04 but there was no sound.  I switched back to Windows so I can have sound. Now I want to switch back to Ubuntu, but this time 17.10. Is there like a work around or something that can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396302/how-can-i-enable-the-drivers-for-beats-audio-speakers-for-hp-envy-dv6) solution. Although it was for beats audio subwoofer issue.
 And add yourself to audio group and restart or relogin.

```
adduser <myself> audio
```